# Company Communities user access to report on Campaign data - possible?

Tags: community, licenses, campaign, campaign-member

I have Company Communities license users who need to view a report on a Campaign with CampaignMembers. I know this license doesn't have access to these objects, but is there a way for them to just view the report (as another user)? I know a dashboard can be run as another user, but what about a report? I can't seem to find anything that suggests it's possible.

The Communities license has all the settings to view public reports/dashboards and create/edit too (but not manage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Irene

This is not possible you need to have at least read access to object.